# How to check if PHP-FPM is running properly?

Tags: php, fpm

The documentation on php fpm website says that php fpm is part for coe php as of 5.3.3

I am running 5.3.10, how can i check that it is working correctly?  I thought it was a service that ran on a port?

Answer (score 83):

Assuming you are on Linux, check if php-fpm is running by searching through the process list:

```
ps aux | grep php-fpm
```

If running over IP (as opposed to over Unix socket) then you can also check for the port:

```
netstat -an | grep :9000
```

Or using nmap:

```
nmap localhost -p 9000
```

Lastly, I've read that you can request the status, but in my experience this has proven unreliable:

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm status
```

Comment: Does phpinfo() let you know? I can see that php-fpm is running but I'm not convinced its configured correctly because phpinfo() still shows mod_php7 as well as mod_fastcgi. Is it possible that both are running?

Answer (score 38):

For php7.0-fpm I call:

```
service php7.0-fpm status
```

> php7.0-fpm start/running, process 25993

Now watch for the good part. The process name is actually php-fpm7.0

```
echo `/bin/pidof php-fpm7.0`
```

> 26334 26297 26286 26285 26282

Answer (score 13):

Here is how you can do it with a socket on php-fpm 7

```
install socat
apt-get install socat

#!/bin/sh

  if echo /dev/null | socat UNIX:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock - ; then
    echo "$home/run/php-fpm.sock connect OK"
  else
    echo "$home/run/php-fpm.sock connect ERROR"
  fi
```

You can also check if the service is running like this.

```
service php7.0-fpm status | grep running
```

It will return

Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-04-09 12:48:09 PDT; 48s ago

Answer (score 6):

in case it helps someone, on amilinux, with php5.6 and php-fpm installed, it's:

`sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm-5.6 status`

Answer (score 1):

PHP-FPM is a service that spawns new PHP processes when needed, usually through a fast-cgi module like nginx.  You can tell (with a margin of error) by just checking the init.d script e.g. "sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm status"

What port or unix file socket is being used is up to the configuration, but often is just TCP port 9000.  i.e. 127.0.0.1:9000

The best way to tell if it is running correctly is to have nginx running, and setup a virtual host that will fast-cgi pass to PHP-FPM, and just check it with wget or a browser.

Answer (score 1):

The bash script for the auto restart php-fpm:

```
#!/bin/bash
is_running=`service php7.4-fpm status | grep running`
if [[ ! $is_running ]]
then
    echo 'php7.4-fpm is running'
else
    echo 'php7.4-fpm is not running';
fi
```

Cron configuration for the checking every 5 minutes(`/root/check_php7.4_status.sh` - path to the bash script):

```
*/5 * * * * /root/check_php7.4_status.sh 2>&1 >> '/root/check_php7.4_status.log'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This could be a decent answer - but there is a bettr way.  You don't need to grep for "running".  The exit code is 0 if the program is working correctly otherwise a different number, so you can just check $? to check if it needs to be actioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling for a while on a Centos 7 server running cPanel and WHM with PHP-FPM becoming unresponsive at times. The PHP-FPM service shows it is running, but does not respond to requests.

The team at my datacenter is also trying to assist me with finding a permanent solution, but thus far we haven't had any luck.

In the interim, I have developed a Node.js monitoring system that operates by opening a test file that runs on PHP FPM. The system utilizes both HTTP:// and HTTPS:// calls while referencing the server's IP address and site hostname to prevent any unwarranted restarts resulting from network, DNS, or other related errors. In the event that the system does not receive a valid response, it restarts PHP FPM and sends me an email.

The code and method is below if anyone may find it useful.

Create a folder on your server e.g. /home/itdint/monitor/ and create a file called monitor.js and init.php in that folder. Create a testFPM.php file on a domain you can test on the server.

---Node Process (monitor.js), the only module you should need to install is axios (e.g. npm install axios)

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const failureEmail = "[your email address]";
const serverIP = "[server ip]"; //e.g. 8.8.8.8
const testDomain = "[your domain name]"; //e.g. example.com
const testFile = "testFPM.php";

const restartFPMCommand = "/scripts/restartsrv_apache_php_fpm";
const failedEmailCommand = 'mail -s \"FPM Restarted\" '+failureEmail+' < /dev/null';

function date(str,timestamp){
    var ret = "";
    if(!timestamp){
        var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    else{
        timestamp = parseInt(timestamp);
    }
    var d = new Date(timestamp*1000);
    
    if(!str){var str = "Y-m-d H:i:s";}
    str = str.split("");
    var strc = str.length;
    for(var a=0;a<strc;a++){
        switch(str[a]) {
            case "d":
                var m = d.getDate()+""; if(m.length < 2){m = "0"+m;}
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "j":
                var m = d.getDate()+"";
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "D":
                var m = d.getDay();
                if(m == 0){m = "Sun";}
                if(m == 1){m = "Mon";}
                if(m == 2){m = "Tue";}
                if(m == 3){m = "Wed";}
                if(m == 4){m = "Thu";}
                if(m == 5){m = "Fri";}
                if(m == 6){m = "Sat";}
                
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "N":
                var m = d.getDay();
                if(m == 0){m = 7;}

                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "w":
                var m = d.getDay();
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "z":
                var start = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
                var diff = d - start;
                var daytime = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                var m = Math.floor(diff / daytime) - 1;

                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "S":
                var m = d.getDate();
                
                if(m == 1 || m == 21 || m == 31){m = "st";}
                if(m == 2 || m == 22){m = "nd";}
                if(m == 3 || m == 23){m = "rd";}
                if((m > 3 && m < 21) || (m > 23 && m < 31)){m = "th";}
                
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "l":
                var m = d.getDay();
                if(m == 0){m = "Sunday";}
                if(m == 1){m = "Monday";}
                if(m == 2){m = "Tuesday";}
                if(m == 3){m = "Wednesday";}
                if(m == 4){m = "Thursday";}
                if(m == 5){m = "Friday";}
                if(m == 6){m = "Saturday";}
                
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "W":
                var dd = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
                dd.setUTCDate(dd.getUTCDate() + 4 - (dd.getUTCDay()||7));
                var year_start = new Date(Date.UTC(dd.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
                var week_no = Math.ceil((((dd-year_start)/86400000)+1)/7);
                var m = week_no + "";
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "F":
                var m = (d.getMonth()+1);
                if(m == 1){m = "January";}
                if(m == 2){m = "February";}
                if(m == 3){m = "March";}
                if(m == 4){m = "April";}
                if(m == 5){m = "May";}
                if(m == 6){m = "June";}
                if(m == 7){m = "July";}
                if(m == 8){m = "August";}
                if(m == 9){m = "September";}
                if(m == 10){m = "October";}
                if(m == 11){m = "November";}
                if(m == 12){m = "December";}
                
                ret = ret + m;
                break;
            case "m":
                var m = (d.getMonth()+1)+""; if(m.length < 2){m = "0"+m;}
                ret = ret + m;
                break; 
            case "M":
                var m = (d.getMonth()+1);
                if(m == 1){m = "Jan";}
                if(m == 2){m = "Feb";}
                if(m == 3){m = "Mar";}
                if(m == 4){m = "Apr";}
                if(m == 5){m = "May";}
                if(m == 6){m = "Jun";}
                if(m == 7){m = "Jul";}
                if(m == 8){m = "Aug";}
                if(m == 9){m = "Sep";}
                if(m == 10){m = "Oct";}
                if(m == 11){m = "Nov";}
                if(m == 12){m = "Dec";}
                
                ret = ret + m;
                break; 
            case "n":
                var m = (d.getMonth()+1)+"";
                ret = ret + m;
                break; 
            case "t":
                var m = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 0);
                m = m.getDate();
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break; 
            case "L":
                var m = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 1, 0);
                m = m.getDate();
                
                if(m == 29){m = "1";}
                else{m = "0";}
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "o":
                ret = ret + d.getFullYear()+"";
                break;
            case "Y":
                ret = ret + d.getFullYear()+"";
                break;
            case "y":
                var m = d.getFullYear()+"";
                m = m.substr((m.length-2),2);
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "a":
                var m = d.getHours();
                if(m < 12){m = "am"}
                else{m = "pm"}; 
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "A":
                var m = d.getHours();
                if(m < 12){m = "AM"} 
                else{m = "PM"}; 

                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "B":
                var m = Math.floor((((d.getUTCHours() + 1) % 24) + d.getUTCMinutes() / 60 + d.getUTCSeconds() / 3600) * 1000 / 24);
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "g":
                var m = d.getHours();
                
                if(m > 12){m = m - 12;}
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "G":
                var m = d.getHours();
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "h":
                var m = d.getHours();
                if(m > 12){m = m - 12;}
                
                m = m + ""; if(m.length < 2){m = "0"+m;}
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "H":
                var m = d.getHours();
                
                m = m + ""; if(m.length < 2){m = "0"+m;}
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "i":
                var m = d.getMinutes();
                
                m = m + ""; if(m.length < 2){m = "0"+m;}
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            case "s":
                var m = d.getSeconds();
                
                m = m + ""; if(m.length < 2){m = "0"+m;}
                
                ret = ret + m + "";
                break;
            default:
                ret = ret + str[a] + "";
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}

function log(message){
    console.log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") + " - "+message)
}

var checking = false;

async function checkStatus(host,type){
    const startTime = Date.now();
    var r = "";
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(type+serverIP+'/'+testFile, {
            timeout: 4000,
            headers: {
                'Host': host,
                // other headers
            }
        })
        const endTime = Date.now();
        const elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 306) {
            if(res.data == "fpm-fcgi"){
                r = 'UP in '+elapsedTime+" => "+res.data;
            }
            else{
                r = 'DOWN ' + res.status + " in "+elapsedTime+" => "+res.data;
            }
        } else {
            r = 'DOWN ' + res.status + " in "+elapsedTime;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        r = 'DOWN ' + err.message;
    }
    
    return r;
}
async function checkAStatus(){
    if(!checking){
        checking = true;

        var httpStatus = await checkStatus(testDomain,"http://");
        var httpsStatus = await checkStatus(testDomain,"https://");

        if(httpStatus.substring(0,4) == "DOWN" || httpsStatus.substring(0,4) == "DOWN"){
            log("Restarting FPM...");

            try {
                const output = execSync(restartFPMCommand);
                console.log(output.toString());
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`execSync error: ${error}`);
            }

            try {
                execSync(failedEmailCommand);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`execSync error: ${error}`);
            }
        }
        
        log("HTTP: "+httpStatus+" | HTTPS: "+httpsStatus);

        checking = false;
    }
    else{
        log("Already checking.");
    }
}
  
// Check the website status every 10 seconds
setInterval(checkAStatus, 10000);
```

--PHP Test File (testFPM.php)

```
<?php
$sapiType = php_sapi_name();
echo $sapiType;
?>
```

--PHP INIT script (init.php) that can be used to start/stop/restart and check the monitor process via cron. This script also outputs the monitor logs to log.log in the same folder and can be used as follows.

php /home/itdint/monitor/init.php check

php /home/itdint/monitor/init.php stop

php /home/itdint/monitor/init.php start

php /home/itdint/monitor/init.php restart

view log file: tail -f /home/itdint/monitor/log.log

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
$command = $argv[1];

global $node_process;
global $pid_file;
global $log_file;
global $log_levels;
global $first_log;

$log_levels = array();
$log_levels["error"] = true;
$log_levels["info"] = false;
$log_levels["general"] = true;

$node_process = "node ".__DIR__."/monitor.js";
$pid_file = __DIR__."/pid";
$log_file = __DIR__."/log";

$first_log = true;

function write_log($data,$type="info",$add=false,$nodate=false){
    global $log_file;
    global $log_levels;
    global $first_log;
    
    if($log_levels[$type]){
        $date_string = "";

        $color = "\x1b[2m";

        if($type == "general"){$color = "\x1b[36m";}
        if($type == "error"){$color = "\x1b[31m";}
        
        if(!$nodate){
            $date = "INIT - ".date("D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (T) ");
        }
        else{
            $date = "";
        }

        $string = "";
        if(!$add && !$first_log){$string .= "\n";}

        $string .= $color;

        if(!$add){$string .= $date;}

        $string .= $data;
        $string .= "\x1b[0m";
        
        if($add){
            $string .= "\n";
        }
        
        file_put_contents($log_file.".log",$string,FILE_APPEND);
        
        $first_log = false;
    }
}

function pid(){
    return "test";
}

function is_running(){
    global $node_process;
    write_log("Checking if process is running.");
    
    $pid = pid();
    
    if($pid != ""){
        exec("ps aux | grep node",$output,$result);
        $outputc = count($output);
        $found = false;
        for($a=0;$a<$outputc;$a++){
            write_log($output[$a]);
            if(strpos($output[$a],$node_process) !== false){
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        
        if($found){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

function start(){
    global $node_process;
    global $client_user;
    if(!is_running()){
        write_log("Starting Node Process:");
        exec("nohup ".$node_process." >> ".__DIR__."/log".".log 2>&1 &");
        write_log("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------","general",false,true);
        write_log("Starting Node Server... ","general");
        
        sleep(1);
        
        if(is_running()){
            write_log("[OK]","general",true);
        }
        else{
            write_log("[FAILED]","error",true);
        }
    }
    else{
        write_log("Process already running");
    }
}

function stop(){
    global $node_process;
    
    if(!is_running()){
        write_log("Process not running.");
    }
    else{
        write_log("Stopping process...","general");
        $pid = "";
        $nout = array();
        $output = array();
        $result = array();
        exec("ps aux | grep '".$node_process."'",$output,$result);
        $outputc = count($output);
        $found = false;
        for($a=0;$a<$outputc;$a++){
            if(strpos($output[$a],$node_process) !== false && strpos($output[$a],"grep") === false){
                /*write_log($output[$a],"general",true);*/
                $found = true;
                $out = explode(" ",$output[$a]);
                $outc = count($out);
                for($a=0;$a<$outc;$a++){
                    if(trim($out[$a]) != ""){
                        $nout[] = $out[$a];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if($found){
            $pid = $nout[1];

            write_log("Killing process ".$pid."... ","general");
            
            exec("kill ".$pid);
            
            if(!is_running()){
                write_log("[OK]","general",true);
            }
            else{
                write_log("[FAILED]","error",true);
            }
        }
        else{
            write_log("[PROCESS NOT FOUND][FAILED]","error",true);
        }
    }
}

function restart(){
    stop();
    start();
}

function check(){
    write_log("Checking if running... ","general");
    if(is_running()){
        write_log("Process is running [OK]","general",true);
    }
    else{
        write_log("Process is not running [FAILED]","error",true);
        restart(); 
    }
}

if($command == ""){$command = "check";}

write_log("Command: ".$command);

if($command == "start"){
    start();
}

if($command == "stop"){
    stop();
}

if($command == "restart"){
    restart();
}

if($command == "check"){
    check();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial - but I think nifty - script I wrote which can be run from CRON and will check that all versions of php-fpm installed on the server are running.  This was written for Ubuntu 22.04, so YMMV.   (This information is partially gleaned from information on this page, but strangely none took the extra step of using the status returned when you run "php-fpm status"

The idea is to do a status check on each version of php-fpm found in /etc/init.d , and then check the return code.  If the return code is not null, something is wrong and we do notifications and attempt a restart.

```
#!/bin/bash

NOTIFY=me@my.address

for each in /etc/init.d/php*fpm
do
    $each status  > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        logger "$each was not running on $( hostname ) "
        mail -s "$each was not running on $( hostname ) " $NOTIFY < /dev/null
        $each restart
    fi
done
```