# How to check PHP-FPM is running properly on a specific domain?

Tags: php, apache, fpm

In cPanel, it is possible to enable PHP-FPM for some domains, and disable for some others.

In my server, there is a strange problem:

1. In cPanel, the PHP-FPM is shown as disabled for domain example.com.
2. in WHM, the PHP-FPM is shown as enabled for the same domain example.com

I doubt this is actually a bug of cPanel, so I want to find a way to check whether PHP-FPM is actually running for domain example.com

I check [How to check if PHP-FPM is running properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915147/how-to-check-if-php-fpm-is-running-properly) but this only check if the PHP-FPM service is running on the server, not for a specific domain.

Comment: Visit the site then check the access log.

Comment: Have you checked `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Good Point. I try and see the following "Server API:FPM/FastCGI". I think that means the PHP-FPM is enabled?

Comment: @shingo, access log in php74-fpm-error.log also shows NOTICE: [pool example_com] child 4779 started, which should means FPM is enabled.